# Download contents of FTP site but only first 10 MB of each file?

Tags: ftp, download

I have an FTP site containing very large files scattered among smaller files.

I want to download the entire FTP contents, but limit the amount downloaded for each file to 10 MB or so.

So all files less than 10 MB will be intact, but all files larger than 10 MB will only get the first 10 MB of data.

Is this at all possible?
If not, is there a way to download all files smaller than 10 MB?

Comment: *curl* should be able to do this... not sure exactly what's necessary offhand; i'll try to look it up later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can use *[cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)* to do it.

It has an option, '-r/--range', which allows me to specify a byte range of filesize.

This will ensure that I will get the first 10 MB of large files and the complete file for anything smaller.

Answer (score 0):

To download all the files smaller than 10 MB you can do this if all the files are in a single folder (assumes you are using a GUI FTP client):

- Sort the files by size - usually by clicking on the filesize header
- Select the first file smaller than 10 MB
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the last file. This will select the range of files.
- Transfer those files

If the files are in multiple folders you'll have to repeat this for each folder.

Comment: this will copy the entire file. OP wants the first 10MB only.

Comment: That's true. This was an answer to the last question in the post. I've clarified the answer to say that.

Comment: There are >1000 folders

Answer (score -1):

To answer you second option for skipping the large files, in [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) you can set up a filter based on file size, and use that to hide/skip files greater than 10 MB.